# How does insurance work in the US in case of long hospitalizations?

Tags: united-states, insurance, inheritance, will

I have been reading some advance directive (living will) documents online and I wondered what happens when one is in the hospital and is in a vegetative state. I am trying to cover my dependents and keep them from making big decisions in depressed emotional state.

- If the person had insurance from the employer, is it still covered?
- What if the person were unconscious during open enrollment and wasn't able to sign up, does the person lose coverage the following year?

I assume that the person's estate is used to settle the hospital bills thereby leaving the beneficiaries with less.

Answer (score 3):

> If the person had insurance from the employer, is it still covered?

If the person is in vegetative state, they'll be covered by the long term disability coverage, if any. You should check your insurance policy to see how the coverage would work in this situation.

Employers may terminate an employee on long term leave, depending on the State, after certain period of time (up to 1 year). You'll keep the disability benefit for as long as you're disabled.

> What if the person were unconscious during open enrollment and wasn't able to sign up, does the person lose coverage the following year?

My experience with open enrollments is that the default is carrying forward the existing selections. You should check with your employer what the policy is.

Comment: And your employer may offer you a choice of plans in addition to arranging your own. And US health insurance is usually somewhat compartmentalized, with vision, dental, mental health and long-term care all separate from basic health coverage. And some plans have varying degrees of restriction to specific providers. And there is a financial incentive to take a High Deductible With Health Savings Account plan. And... You really need to look at exactly what's available to you and your needs if you care about making the best decisions.